# Polling a constantly updating text file to cut selected information

Tags: perl, awk, grep, real-time, text-processing

I have a log tail running in real time and saving to a text file using the 'script' command named 'test.txt' at /home/pi/ also in real time. Now I want to set up a process that constantly polls that text file for changes and cuts out a specific reoccurring bit of data. For example, a section of the log would look like:

```
Feb  9 11:43:24 dnsmasq[887]: query[A] captive.g.aaplimg.com from 192.168.178.21
Feb  9 11:43:24 dnsmasq[887]: forwarded captive.g.aaplimg.com to 8.8.4.4
Feb  9 11:43:24 dnsmasq[887]: reply captive.g.aaplimg.com is 17.253.55.202
Feb  9 11:43:24 dnsmasq[887]: reply captive.g.aaplimg.com is 17.253.57.211
Feb  9 11:43:54 dnsmasq[887]: query[A] captive.g.aaplimg.com from 192.168.178.21
```

And I want to cut info only from the lines with query[A] (assuming that could be used as a marker) so that the output text looks like:

```
11:43 captive.g.aaplimg.com
```

But the problem is that there are different URL's attached to this line of the log, so for example a line with 'query[A]' could also look like:

```
Feb  9 11:49:56 dnsmasq[887]: query[A] www.googleapis.com from 192.168.178.21
```

Then I would want the output to be:

```
11:49 www.googleapis.com
```

But it needs to happen in real-time, as the text file/log is updating because I want this text file to be constantly polled and sent to a printer also in real time (a long story)

I have been looking at awk + sed to cut out the info I need, but they're new to me so I find the format a bit confusing, and i find it especially hard to figure out how to run it so it happens in real time.

Running on debian buster on pi.

Would love some help! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage people to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add so and let us know then.

Comment: Naturally! Should've mentioned it

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're looking for something like this:

```
tail -f my.log | perl -nle 'print"$1$2" if /(\d\d:\d\d):\d\d.*query\[A\]( \S+)/' > test.txt
```

The `-f` constantly outputs the last lines as the file `my.log` grows. It feeds the lines into the little perl one-liner program which looks for `query[A]` (escaping the `[` and `]` chars with `\` since they otherwise have special meaning in regexpes) and when found outputs the time in hours and minutes and the domain name captured by the regexp into `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: To do it all in Perl, once could use [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail)